# Press ENTER to continue

Tags: shell-script, scripting, sleep, stty, wait

I want to know if there is any way to make my script stop until the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, but without using the command `read`, just by the options of `stty`.

I was wondering a code for this and got some search; so I found a code that needs "space" to continue and changed the variable `hold` from empty space to `\n`, but no success.

That's how it looks like:

```
function _enter-to-continue() {
    local hold='\n'        # this solution i tried, but without success

    printf "Press 'ENTER' to continue or 'ESC' to cancel... "
    local original_tty_state=$(stty -g)
    trap "stty $original_tty_state; exit 0" 2
    stty intr \033

    stty raw isig noflsh echo icrnl

    until [ -z "${hold#$in}" ]; do
        in=$(dd bs=1 count=1 </dev/tty 2>/dev/null)
    done

    stty "$original_tty_state"
}
```

Comment: Umm... What's the reasoning around not using `read`? Also, what shell are you writing for, `bash`? A literal newline in `bash` could be written `$'\n'`.

Comment: 1) I was searching for a method that does not allows the writing of any text, avoiding the 'read -s -p "Press ENTER..." var' workaround, and being validated just with the exclusive usage of a specified key, in this case ENTER. 2) Yes: coding for bash.

Answer (score 2):

I must admin that I did not read the question thoroughly enough. One of the reasons is that your intention is not related to terminal settings at all, with the exception of `icrnl` which is the default setting anyway.

`[ -z "${hold#$in}" ]` is a rather strange way to express `[ "$in" = ' ' ]` or `[ "$hold" = "$in" ]`. The problem or your code is that `$(cmd)` strips off a trailing newline. You are waiting for just a newline... So the wanted character never arrives at the testing code. You need

```
in=$(dd bs=1 count=1 </dev/tty 2>/dev/null; echo x)
in="${in%x}"
```

The other problem is `local hold='\n'`. That doesn't work, this is not C. You need

```
hold='
'
# or
hold=$'\n'
```

### Waiting for <kbd>Enter</kbd> without `read`

```
head -n 1 >/dev/null
```

This could replace the whole `until` loop But would be limited to newline.

Comment: Please, give me more details: where I would put that line?

Comment: @RegisBarbosa I changed my answer.

Comment: Great solution with `head`! Thank you!